Azure blob trigger after failover to the secondary region
We have a azure blob storage container of type Ra GRS. during failover from East to Central region. We see azure blob triggers for the files which were already existing in the East. We were assuming only for the new files that go into the central. We would have blob triggers. Isn't that the behavior?

what triggers are you talking about? storage event triggers in ADF? or triggers in azure functions? Edit your question to add the total information about your scenario and types of triggers that you have used? and also add the exact blocker and expected output?
